# Block all RDP connection except one IP

Tags: rdp, hyper-v-server-2012-r2, ip-blocking

I want to block all connection to Hyper-V machine except from one IP.
I can explain my scenario.
User can access RDP when they are in our company network.We are using 128.x.x.x range internally and have one static public ip 125.x.x.x.x.
Please guide me step by step.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the Windows Firewall (Advanced firewall) and allow port 3389 or default `User mode` rules for a specific remote IP.

1) Open Windows Firewall with advanced security
2) Find the following two fules:
[image: Firewall rules]
3) Edit them, go to the tab scope and add a remote address:
[image: Scope tab]
4) Click OK and enable both rules

Comment: We are using AVG antivirus and AVG firewall is enabled in RDP machine.Can i do the same thing in AVG firewall?

Comment: @Nuhus: I have no experience with AVG, so no idea really.